Different number of <br>s in XSLT rendering in Chrome and Firefox


<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE message  [ <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet id ID #REQUIRED> ]>
<message>
  <xsl:stylesheet id="style1" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body>
          line 1
          <br/>
          line 2
        </body>

      </html>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</message>



I validated the XML syntax at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp :


In Chrome, the above XML file renders with two <br>s:

In Firefox, the above XML file renders with one <br>:

I wonder which is correct? One <br> or two <br>?

What happens if you use xsl:output method="xml" as you use XHTML?

I am pretty sure the correct answer is 1. Does the same problem occur with <xsl:element name="br"/> in place of <br/>? What about other empty HTML elements like <meta> - do they have the same problem?

The XSLT implementations of Chrome/Chromium based browsers and Firefox/Mozilla are much different, Firefox transforms the XML input tree with XSLT into an HTML or XHTML result tree. Chrome, meanwhile, as far as I understand it, use libxslt to create a serialized transformation result that is then fed to a parser, if you use output method="html", if will be the text/html / HTML5 parser, if you use output method="xml", it will be the XML parser. The HTML5 parser might parse the serialized transformation result into two br elements, it would be worth checking what the HTML5 validators do.

I think libxslt serializes the empty <br/> as XML <br></br>, if it is then parsed as HTML that indeed creates two HTML br elements https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/test2024071501.html in Chrome.

And even Firefox renders <html><br></br></html> as two line breaks. But it is invalid HTML according to https://validator.w3.org/check (it is valid XHTML, however). To avoid the problem, omit the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" from the <html> element.

Just be aware this might actually be a dev tools thing. I've noticed before that sometimes a newline shows up as a  in dev tools

As @MartinHonnen 's link demonstrates, the issue is real, you see an unwanted empty line.

@MartinHonnen: If https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/test2024071501.html were loaded with Content-Type: application/xml, Chrome would display it correctly.

@HeikoTheißen, well, that sample is meant to investigate and explain the result of the original sample. I suggested to use xsl:output method="xml" from the beginning to fix the posted stylesheet. And the proper MIME type to serve XHTML as XML is application/xhtml+xml, not application/xml. So yes, if treated/served as X(HT)ML, the Chrome browser obviously uses an XML parser and knows how to deal with <br></br>.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78769613/treatment-of-superfluous-closing-tags-depends-on-tag-name
